# Passar valores por referência C

Tags: c, struct

Tenho que fazer um programa com menu de opções que me permita ler as informações de um aluno, escrever o nome e o telefone depois de introduzido o seu numero de aluno e determinar quantos alunos têm idade superior a uma idade introduzida pelo utilizador. O programa corre, mas não me grava os dados. Queria saber se me podem ajudar neste problema!!

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct aluno{
    int numero;
    char nome[100];
    char morada[100];
    int idade;
    int telefone;
};

void infoPerson(struct aluno *Turma, int *i) {


    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        printf("Introduza o número \n");
        scanf(" %d", &Turma->numero);
        printf("Introduza a idade \n");
        scanf(" %d", &Turma->idade);
        printf("Introduza o telefone \n");
        scanf(" %d", &Turma->telefone);
        printf("Introduza o nome \n");
        scanf(" %s", &Turma->nome[100]);
        printf("Introduza a morada \n");
        scanf(" %s", &Turma->morada[100]);
    }
}

int main() {
    int opc;
    int i = 0;
    struct aluno *Turma[2];
    do{
        do{
            printf("1 - Introduzir alunos\n");
            printf("2 - Teste\n");
            printf("3 - Teste\n");
            scanf("%d", &opc);
        } while (opc < 0 || opc > 3);
        switch (opc){
            case 1:
                infoPerson(Turma, &i);
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("\n");
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("Teste\n");
        }
    } while (opc < 0 || opc > 3);
}
```

Comment: Este código nem compila em um compilador configurado adequadamente.

Comment: No meu IDE (CLion) ele corre com alguns erros.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

O código tem diversos erros, acho que é isso que deseja:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int numero;
    char nome[100];
    char morada[100];
    int idade;
    int telefone; //o tipo está errado
} Aluno;

void infoPerson(Aluno *turma, int limite) {
    for (int i = 0; i < limite; i++) {
        printf("Introduza o número \n");
        scanf(" %d", &turma[i].numero);
        printf("Introduza a idade \n");
        scanf(" %d", &turma[i].idade);
        printf("Introduza o telefone \n");
        scanf(" %d", &turma[i].telefone);
        printf("Introduza o nome \n");
        scanf(" %99s", turma[i].nome);
        printf("Introduza a morada \n");
        scanf(" %99s", turma[i].morada);
    }
}

int main() {
    int opc;
    Aluno turma[2];
    do {
        printf("1 - Introduzir alunos\n");
        printf("2 - Teste\n");
        printf("3 - Teste\n");
        scanf("%d", &opc);
        switch (opc) {
            case 1:
                infoPerson(turma, 2);
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("\n");
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("\n");
                break;
        }
    } while (opc < 0 || opc > 3);
    printf("%s - %d\n", turma[0].nome, turma[0].idade);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Ej5gzR). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/vihgrjjv-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/ReferencePass.c).

Depois eu detalho os erros. O código ainda não é bom.

Comment: Sim, o telefone tem que ser um unsigned int. O que significa o "%99s"? Obrigado pela ajuda!!

Comment: Não, ele tem que ser um `char[12]`, quase nada deve ser uint. A formatação de entrada só permite 99 caracteres.

Comment: Certo, obrigado. Com este código assim agora acho que consigo fazer o resto que me faltava